# Dagger 2 injecting view model of activity into fragment

Tags: android, kotlin, dagger-2

(using kotlin) I have an app that uses a settings activity with 2 fragments. I'd like both to get the same instance of the SettingsViewModel as the activity. I assume there's a scoping issue that I'm missing.

First, I have the standard `ViewModelModule`:

```
@Module
abstract class ViewModelModule {
    @Binds @IntoMap
    @ViewModelKey(SettingsViewModel::class)
    abstract fun bindSettingsViewModel(viewModel: SettingsViewModel): ViewModel

    @Binds
    abstract fun bindViewModelFactory(factory: MyViewModelFactory): ViewModelProvider.Factory
}
```

I bind my activities in:

```
@Module
abstract class AndroidBindingModule {
    @PerActivity
    @ContributesAndroidInjector(modules = [SettingsActivityModule::class])
    abstract fun contributeSettingsActivity(): SettingsActivity
}
```

With all other things in place this works well and `SettingsActivity` does get an instance of the `SettingsViewModel`. `SettingsActivityModule` adds the following:

```
@PerFragment
@ContributesAndroidInjector
abstract fun contributeMainSettingsFragment(): MainSettingsFragment

@PerFragment
@ContributesAndroidInjector
abstract fun contributeDebugSettingsFragment(): DebugSettingsFragment
```

Both fragments appear to have the injectors called on them (I've checked through the debugger and `AndroidSupportInjection.inject(fragment)` is called). The fragments include:

```
@Inject lateinit var mainViewModel: SettingsViewModel
```

But in my fragment's `onCreate()` I'm seeing that `mainViewModel` is still null. Is there anything special I need to do here to avoid calling `ViewModelProviders.of(activity)[SettingsViewModel::class.java]` and instead injecting the view model?

UPDATE:

After a bit more reading I found that the correct way of using the view model injection in fragments is to inject the factory and get the view model in `onActivityCreated`:

```
@Inject lateinit var viewModelFactory: ViewModelProvider.Factory
lateinit var mainViewModel: SettingsViewModel

override fun onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState)
    mainViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(activity, viewModelFactory)[SettingsViewModel::class.java]
}
```

This makes sense since I have `MyViewModelFactory` bound as the `ViewModelProvider.Factory` and it's annotated with `@Singleton`. When I try to compile the above I get the following error:

```
Error:(6, 1) error: [dagger.android.AndroidInjector.inject(T)] java.util.Map<kotlin.reflect.KClass<? extends android.arch.lifecycle.ViewModel>,? extends javax.inject.Provider<android.arch.lifecycle.ViewModel>> cannot be provided without an @Provides-annotated method.
```

It appears that Dagger can't find the mapping created by the `ViewModelModule`. I'm still at a loss at how that can be. Maybe my tree is incorrect? Why would activities in `AndroidBindingModule` be able to get the ViewModel but not fragments?

```
AppComponent
  - AndroidInjectionModule
  - AndroidBindingModule
  - AppModule
    - SdkModule
    - ViewModelModule
    - GotItCardModule
    - ViewHolderSubcomponent (provides a mapping of layout ID -> ViewHolder for a factory)
```

UPDATE

I've done a little more digging into this... From the full error:

```
e: /home/user/workspace/Example/sdktest/build/tmp/kapt3/stubs/debug/com/example/sdktest/di/AppComponent.java:6: error: [dagger.android.AndroidInjector.inject(T)] java.util.Map<kotlin.reflect.KClass<? extends android.arch.lifecycle.ViewModel>,? extends javax.inject.Provider<android.arch.lifecycle.ViewModel>> cannot be provided without an @Provides-annotated method.
e: 

e: public abstract interface AppComponent {
e:                 ^
e:       java.util.Map<kotlin.reflect.KClass<? extends android.arch.lifecycle.ViewModel>,? extends javax.inject.Provider<android.arch.lifecycle.ViewModel>> is injected at
e:           com.example.sdktest.di.viewmodel.ExampleViewModelFactory.<init>(creators)
e:       com.example.sdktest.di.viewmodel.ExampleViewModelFactory is injected at
e:           com.example.sdktest.di.viewmodel.ViewModelModule.bindViewModelFactory(factory)
e:       android.arch.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider.Factory is injected at
e:           com.example.sdktest.ui.settings.fragment.MainSettingsFragment.viewModelFactory
e:       com.example.sdktest.ui.settings.fragment.MainSettingsFragment is injected at
e:           dagger.android.AndroidInjector.inject(arg0)
```

I think the issue is that somehow Dagger is trying to inject my fragment with `dagger.android.AndroidInjecton` instead of `dagger.android.AndroidSupportInjection`. Still not sure how to fix.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

OK, so I found the answer and it wasn't anywhere near what I thought. My translation of the [GithubViewModelFactory](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture-components/blob/master/GithubBrowserSample/app/src/main/java/com/android/example/github/viewmodel/GithubViewModelFactory.java) into Kotlin included the following constructor:

```
@Singleton
class MetaverseViewModelFactory @Inject constructor(
        creators: Map<KClass<out ViewModel>, Provider<ViewModel>>
): ViewModelProvider.Factory {
    private val creators: Map<Class<out ViewModel>, Provider<ViewModel>> =
            creators.mapKeys { it.key.java }
    //...
}
```

This was due to the `ViewModelKey` in Kotlin being able to use `KClass` only instead of `Class`. It turns out that kapt takes care of this and the correct factory should look like:

```
@Singleton
class MetaverseViewModelFactory @Inject constructor(
        private val creators: Map<Class<out ViewModel>, @JvmSuppressWildcards Provider<ViewModel>>
): ViewModelProvider.Factory {
    //...
}
```

Note the additional `@JvmSupressWildcards` to also avoid turning `Provider<ViewModel>` into `Provider<? extends ViewModel>`